# Jquery loop through each cart and grab the data of its class

Tags: jquery

I have a class called `cartRow` and this contains classes for title, session, date, etc and I'm trying to grab each of its data individually, which is why it includes its index such as __0 or __1 or __2 always assigned to it.

Can a jquery expert assist me so I can individually alert the data?

```
<div class="row cartRow">
    <div class="col-xs-12 cartItemHeader">
        <h3 class="title__0">Hello World 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 cartItemDetail">
        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-5">
            <div class="row no-gutter">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="session__0">Fall</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="dates__0">November</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="faculty__0">Jones</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="hours__0">3</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row cartRow">
    <div class="col-xs-12 cartItemHeader">
        <h3 class="title__1">Hello World 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 cartItemDetail">
        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-5">
            <div class="row no-gutter">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="session__1">Fall</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="dates__1">December</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="faculty__1">Smith</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="hours__1">3</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you dont need to use those special indicators (as if they were ids), because it pretty much renders the use of classes in that case as useless. the beauty of classes is that you can target a general group of something that you can apply the same type of functionality to instead of using individual unique markers and apply the same functionality to each one of the items separately.

with that being said, you can use `.each()` and `.find()` and classes to accomplish your task:

**EDITED as per comments**

there's an edited section in the js, as well as i added `itemIndex` attribute in the html to the `.cartRow` div elements so that you can more easily differentiate etc. this will help with your want to give uniqueness to the sets of data.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataSet = []; // initialize dataSet array
 $('.cartRow').each(function() {
     var title = $(this).find('.title').html();
        var session = $(this).find('.session').text();
        var dates = $(this).find('.dates').text();
        var faculty = $(this).find('.faculty').text();
        var hours = $(this).find('.hours').text();
        var index = $(this).attr('itemIndex');
        $('.results').append(index + ', ' + title + ', ' + session + ', ' + dates + ', ' + faculty + ', ' + hours + '<br/>');
        // you can do whatever you want with this information now
        
        // EDITED PART THAT MAY HELP YOU WITH THE NEED FOR INDIVIDUAL DATA SETS
        // creat a new object with this data inside of it;
        var item = {
            'title': title,
            'session': session,
            'dates': dates,
            'faculty': faculty,
            'hours': hours,
        };
        dataSet[index] = item; // add object to array dataSet
    });
    
    $('.getInfo').on('click', function() {
     var selectIndex = $('.selectIndex').val();
        var selectType = $('.selectValueType').val();
        var result = '';
        if (selectIndex != '' && selectType != '') {
            result = dataSet[selectIndex][selectType];
        }
        $('.specificResults').html(result);                           
    });    
    
    // my specific information that i want
    // dataSet[desiredIndexNumber].desiredType
    console.log("faculty: "+ dataSet[2].faculty + ", Session: "+ dataSet[2].session + '');
});
```

```css
.cartRow {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row cartRow" itemIndex = "1">
    <div class="col-xs-12 cartItemHeader">
        <h3 class="title">Hello World 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 cartItemDetail">
        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-5">
            <div class="row no-gutter">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="session">Fall</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="dates">November</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="faculty">Jones</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="hours">3</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row cartRow" itemIndex = "2">
    <div class="col-xs-12 cartItemHeader">
        <h3 class="title">Hello World 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 cartItemDetail">
        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-5">
            <div class="row no-gutter">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="session">Fall</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="dates">December</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="faculty">Smith</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="hours">3</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="results">
    <strong>Results</strong><br/>
</div>
<br/><br/>
Type in Index number: <input class="selectIndex" type="text" /><br/>
Type in Data Value Type: (title, session, dates, faculty, hours)<input class="selectValueType" type="text" /><br/>
<button class="getInfo">Get Information Pls</button><br/>
<strong>Results</strong><br/>
<div class="specificResults">
</div>
```

Comment: The __0 and the __1 was important so I send the individual data to my analytic package. I was just hoping on top of this, I could select "title__1" vs "dates__2" instead this concept groups them together. I understand class are meant to be general.

Comment: if you want to store the data individually, perhaps you can create an array of objects to help you out...let me see if i can whip something up to show you what i'm talking about

Comment: Thank you. I look forward to reviewing that

Comment: @Evan, see edited answer above. created a demo to show you how to get specific pieces of information from the array of objects created by the individual data sets. if it doesnt suit your needs, let me know and i'll try to find an alternative way.

Comment: *edit* Ok. you've convinced me that I need to remove my unique classes instead have my developer append an index item to my cartRow. However, my last question is, how can I simply alert or console log JUST the data I want instead of using your awesome click form? Example: alert("faculty: "+faculty2+", Session: "+session2) that I can talk to the individual data? Thank you again. I just need that last piece so I can move the captured data around.

Comment: @evan, check the console log (i updated). i also changed a little of the structure of the objects created that will better suit your purposes (pulled the index property to the outside, so the object is now referenced by indexNumber), so please be wary of those slight changes since my previous edit. you can check out how to reference your desired information in the bottom of the js section, i commented it for you

Comment: This is it! This is exactly what I need. I can use this now for so much with my project If you have a donation button, I'd like to make a small donation/tip for your help. Thank you for being so kind

Comment: You're welcome, and no need. I do this for fun and it keeps my brain on my toes. gl with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the unique classes that have the indexing added to them. It is very easy to isolate the common classes within instances of a parent class.

```
<span class="session">Fall</span>
```

Then you can map all the data within each instance of `cartItemDetail` but you may also want an identifier on each parent

```
<div class="col-xs-12 cartItemDetail" data-item_id="356">
```

JS to produce array of objects representing each cart item

```
var details =['session', 'dates','faculty', 'hours'];
var cartArray = $('.cartItemDetail').map(function(){
   var $cartElem = $(this);
   var data ={
       item_id: $cartElem.data('item_id')
    }
    $.each(details, function(i, className){
        data[className] = $cartElem.find('.'+className).text();
    });
    return data
}).get();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f5rqnsLh/)**</kbd>

Comment: darn, i was hoping to use the index __0 and __1 etc

Comment: for what? can add it to parent. You can use it but it is not usual to create unique classes so it could be used other ways

Comment: I wanted to use the individual data variable in other areas so I can mix into our analytical package.

Comment: no reason it needs to be in `class`. Classses aren't meant to be unique identifiers

Comment: I understand, but I plan to reuse these classes so I can append to multiple locations to send to my analytical package

Comment: if you insist on needing them this code could be modified by changing the selector within `$.each` to an attribute selector

Comment: Could you demonstrate that with my class names? thank you so much

Comment: `$cartElem.find('[class^='+className+']').text();`

Comment: As awesome as this is, I had a unique request to get the data of each of the unique classes.

Comment: and with that change it will do it. Please understand that this isn't a code writing request service